# add extra include directories config on podspec file

Tags: ios, tensorflow, plugins, podspec

In plugin ios, I import library as below

[image]

Currently I have some  `.h` file like `tflite-dist/include/tensorflow/lite/c/model.h`.
In ImageSegmentator.cpp. I want to import like below

```
#include "tensorflow/lite/c/model.h"
```

But when I compile it throws errors `fatal error: 'tensorflow/lite/c/model.h' file not found` .

I try to set up folder `tflite-dist/include/tensorflow/lite/` as same Classes folder

```
s.source_files = 'Classes/**/*', 'cpp/include/**', 'tflite-dist/include/**'
s.resources = ['cpp/include/**', 'tflite-dist/include/**']
```

It did not work. In CMakeLists.txt I see they can config like

```
# add extra include directories
target_include_directories(
    ./src/main/cpp/include
    ${Tensorflowlite_DIR}/include
)
```

But I dont know how we can config like this on podspec file.